# What could be causing lots of outbound and inbound UDP traffic on random ports?

Tags: windows-xp

I'm picking up some strange traffic from seemingly random IP addresses on seemingly random ports. I have checked and ended all the processes in which I think would use any traffic but there is still lots of traffic flowing through my machine.

Some of the ports mentioned are: 12002, 15724, 33041, 63821

What could be causing it? Could I have some sort of virus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a capture of the traffic using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and analyse it at your leisure. This should give you an idea of whether the traffic is being originated from your machine and what the contents are. You could always post an excerpt of it here for other people to look at.

Answer (score -1):

Well of course you could have some sort of virus. In fact I'd be surprised if you didn't. Why are you asking us instead of scanning the machine and finding out for yourself?